# AngularJS. Can't push items in object and repeat it on page

Tags: angularjs

I need to create new obj and push it to arr in my services. Then need to repeat obj on page with ng-repeat. It's a simple admin panel.
I don't really know what's wrong with this code. 
This is my controller:

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function (global) {
vm = this;
vm.items = global.getCards();
vm.currentItem = {};
vm.addItem = function () {
    if (!vm.currentItem.id) {
        let id = global.getCardId();
        vm.currentItem.id = id++;
        global.setCardId(id);
        vm.items.push(vm.currentItem);
        console.log(vm.items);
    }
    vm.currentItem = {};
}
```

### HTML code

Here I use repeat in table like test before it goes to home page:

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th scope="row" ng-repeat='x in dashboard.items track by id'></th>
  <td>{{x.id}}</td>
  <td>{{x.title}}</td>
  <td>{{x.description}}</td>
  <td><i ng-class="{{x.icon}}"></i></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="editItem(x)" 
  value="Edit" name="" id=""></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng- 
  click="removeItem(x.id)" value="Delit" name="" id=""></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my services.
Here I created some functions to get data to pages:

```
app.factory('global', function(){
let _cardId = 4;
let _cards = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "First Title",
    description: "Here must be something special",
    icon: "fa fa-check"
},{
    id: 2,
    title: "Second Title",
    description: "Here must be something special",
    icon: "fa fa-check"
},{
    id: 3,
    title: "Third Title",
    description: "Here must be something special",
    icon: "fa fa-check"
}]
return {
   getCards: function(){
        return _cards;
    },
    getCardId: function(){
        return _cardId;
    },
    setCardId: function(cardId){
        if(cardId<_cardId) alert('error');
        else _cardId = cardId;
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Have you tried to put this `vm.items = global.getCards();` inside your `addItem` function?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work.

Comment: Change your HTML. Put your `repeat` on the `<tr>` and use `track by x.id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your HTML. Put your `repeat` on the `<tr>` and use `track by x.id`. – Luiz Carlos

Answer (score 0):

There are two things,

1. We have to use controller alias `dashboardCtrl as dashboard`, since you bound like `dashboard.items`.
2. Table structure is not correct. Just put like this,

   `<table ng-controller="dashboardCtrl as dashboard">
     <tr>
       <th>Id</th>
       <th>Title</th> 
       <th>Description</th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat='x in dashboard.items'>
       <td>{{x.id}}</td>
         <td>{{x.title}}</td>
         <td>{{x.description}}</td>
         <td><i ng-class="{{x.icon}}"></i></td>
         <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="editItem(x)" 
     value="Edit" name="" id=""></td>
       <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng- 
     click="removeItem(x.id)" value="Delit" name="" id=""></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     </tr>
   </table>`

Comment: Thank's but I have this in routing settings file.

Comment: `HTML` never minds about where you have that file, it just needs a correct table structure. Also Angular never worries about the file location, it just needs a appropriate 'alias'. That's all.